# C: is there any equivalent to `&arr[0]` for 2 dimensional arrays?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to pass a (statically allocated) 2 dimensional array as argument to a function that expects a double pointer. Is this possible ? When I have a single dimensional array like the following for example:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

and a function that expects a pointer like so:

```
void foo (int *arr, int len)
```

I can pass it to the function using the address of the first element (or simply the array name)

```
foo (&arr[0], (sizeof arr /sizeof arr[0])) 
// or 
foo (arr, (sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]))
```

Now I was wondering if this can be extended to a 2 dimensional array. So if I had something like:

```
int matrix[3][3] = { 
    {1, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 1},
}, rows = 3, cols = 3;
```

and if I had to pass it to a function with the following prototype:

```
void foo (int **m, int rows, int cols)
```

Can I pass the 2d array, similarly ?

```
foo (&(&m[0][0]), rows, cols)
foo (&m[0], rows, cols)
foo (m, rows, cols)
```

don't work. Is it even possible? Do I have to change the prototype to accept an array instead ?

Comment: You're confusing jagged-arrays with 2D arrays.

Comment: C stores all memory contigously. https://ukacademe.com/QuestionsBank/CProgramming/Two_Dimensional_Array_Stored_In_Memory#:~:text=Though%20a%20is%20pictured%20as,Row%20Major%20Order
So passing the first element and accessing the 2d array is still valid.

Comment: `int matrix[][] = {` will not compile.

Comment: @KamilCuk sorry I meant `int matrix[3][3] {`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

So, given the declaration

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

when you call

```
foo( arr, 5 );
```

the *expression* `arr` "decays" from type "5-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`" and the value is equivalent to `&arr[0]`.

So now let's imagine the following declaration:

```
int arr[2][3] = { {0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5} };
```

If we call `foo` as

```
foo( arr, 2 );
```

the *expression* `arr` "decays" from type "2-element array of 3-element array of `int`" to "pointer to *3-element array* of `int`".  So in order for this to work, the prototype for `foo` needs to be

```
void foo( int (*arr)[3], int len )
```

Now, you have a bit of a problem - a pointer to a 3-element array of `int` is a distinct type from a pointer to a 2-element array of `int`, which is a distinct type from a pointer to a 4-element array of `int`, etc.  This can *only* work for `len`x3 arrays.  But, there is a way around it - you can use a variable-length array in the prototype, you just have to declare the size first:

```
void foo( size_t s, int (*arr)[s], int len )
```

So, you could do something like this:

```
int a1[2][3] = { {0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5} };
int a2[3][2] = { {0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5} };

foo( 3, a1, 2 );
foo( 2, a2, 3 );
```

But, VLAs aren't the best solution for a number of reasons (not least of which is the syntax still isn't universally supported).  Honestly, the best solution I know of is to treat the array as 1D by passing an explicit pointer to the first element, then passing the number of rows *and* columns as separate parameters, and manually computing the 2D index:

```
void foo( int *arr, size_t rows, size_t cols )
{
  size_t i, j;
  ...
  arr[i * rows + j] = some_value();
  ...
}
```

Thus, you'd call it as

```
foo( &a1[0][0], 2, 3 );
foo( &a2[0][0], 3, 2 );
```

Comment: *But, VLAs aren't the best solution for a number of reasons (not least of which is the syntax still isn't universally supported)* VLAs are generally available on x86 and other widely-used systems. Just because Microsoft can't update their C compiler to the end of the 20th century (MSVC still isn't ***C99*** compliant...) even with 20% of the 21st century already over is no reason to ignore useful C syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Using a single pointer we can do this, we need to typecast the 2D array when passing to function.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void print(int *arr, int m, int n) 
{ 

    int i, j; 

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) 

      for (j = 0; j < n; j++) 

        printf("%d ", *((arr+i*n) + j)); 
} 

  

int main() 
{ 

    int arr[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}; 

    int m = 3, n = 3; 

  

    // We can also use "print(&arr[0][0], m, n);" 

    print((int *)arr, m, n); 

    return 0; 
}
```

example was taken from geeksforgeeks

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
int matrix[][] = { 
    {1, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 1},
};
```

you can not in general pass it to a function of the form

```
void foo (int **m, int rows, int cols)
```

In this case, `foo` almost certainly expects what is all too often mislabeled as a "2-dimensional array", created by code something like this:

```
int **notA2dArray = malloc( rows * sizeof( *notA2dArray ) );
for ( int ii = 0; ii < row; ii++ )
{
    notA2dArray[ ii ] = malloc ( cols * sizeof( **notA2dArray ) );
}
```

That's actually a ***one-dimensional*** array of pointers to multiple, separate ***one-dimensional*** arrays of actual `int` values.

If you try to interpret `int matrix[3][3]` as an `int **`, you will not get the results you expect.  You'll invoke undefined behavior and probably crash your program.

What will probably happen is the address of the actual two-dimensional array is passed to the function, and the function will then dereference that `( *int )[][3]` value as an `int **` pointer.  On most 32-bit systems, that will cause the first `int` element of the actual 2-d array, or `array[0][0]` in the original array, to be interpreted as an `int *` pointer.  That value will then be dereferenced to try to get the first value of the array-of-pointers-to-many-arrays - but `array[0][0]` in an actual array of `int` (or array of `float` or array of `double` or array of `struct foo`...) is ***not*** a pointer, so the dereference likely fails and your program will crash.

On most 64-bit systems, `int` values are 32 bits so the function will try to treat some combination of the actual 2-d array's `array[0][0]` and `array[0][1]` values as the `int *` that it tries to dereference.  And again that's not correct.

Or, it can fail in many other ways.

It's also possible that it might appear to work properly, although that's not likely at all.

If you need to process variable-sized but actual 2-dimensional arrays, you can use [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) in C99 (optional in C11+, but no implementation I'm aware of that was C99 conforming removed VLAs):

```
void printIntArray( int rows, int cols, int array[ rows ][ cols ] )
{
    for ( int ii = 0; ii < rows; ii++ )
    {
        for ( int jj = 0; jj < cols; jj++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", array[ ii ][ jj ] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```